# Looking for specific slider type/header effect for Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, slider

I'm looking to mimic this site's "slider" where the page scrolls up over the slider image: http://callcenter.com/

I'm not sure what search terms to Google or what plugins may help me achieve this look, but I can tell you that I do own the Visual Composer and LayerSlider plugins.

If anyone can tell me what type of header effect/slider that is, I can handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's parallax background slider ?

You can try - https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-simple-jquery-parallax-background/